# How to write paintEvent() for Subclassed QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, paintevent

I SubClassed QComboBox in order to customize it. I wrote the following paintEvent() method to test to see that my style sheet was being applied properly before I started with the customization. However, if I use this paintEvent, the selected item is not being displayed(the already selected one -or- the one I newly select).

```
class MyComboBox: public QComboBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyComboBox(QWidget *parent = 0): QComboBox(parent){}

    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* pEvent)
    {
    QStylePainter painter(this);
    QStyleOptionComboBox opt;
    initStyleOption(&opt);
    painter.drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_ComboBox, opt);
    QVariant itemData = this->itemData( this->currentIndex(), Qt::DisplayRole);
    if(!itemData.isNull() && qVariantCanConvert<QPen>(itemData))
        style()->drawItemText(&painter,this->rect(),Qt::AlignLeft,(this->palette()), true, itemData.toString());
    }
};
```

How do I fix the paintEvent? Also, is there documentation on the paintEvent for different Qt Controls?

Comment: Try to add `QComboBox::paintEvent(pEvent)` to the end of your function.

Comment: @hank What would that achieve? The OP is already explicitly drawing the combobox.

Comment: @go4sri Can you describe what exactly _is_ drawn? (Or even better, post a picture).

Comment: @hank - yes. this solved the problem. I am able to see content. I am now going to try see if the style sheet is applied.

Comment: @cmannett85 : The box was drawn, but the selected item was not being shown in the box. With this change, the selected content is being shown.

Comment: @go4sri Then I don't understand what you were trying to achieve, by calling the base class method you are wiping all the painting you have done and just painting a 'normal' `QComboBox` - you may as well delete the entire method as it would have the same effect.

Comment: Remove ` && qVariantCanConvert<QPen>(itemData)`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is that you override the base class method without calling it first in your derived class. You should call it in your derived class method